# Complex line bundle at symplectic manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

Let's say that there is a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ with condition of $[\omega / 2\pi ]\in H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$.

Then in what condition can I get a complex line bundle $L\twoheadrightarrow M$ in what condition?

Does it have to satisfy condition of $c_1(L)=[\omega/2\pi]$?
Here, $c_1$ is chern class.

Comment: See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+quantization

Comment: How about the trivial complex line bundle? What conditions do you want exactly?

Comment: What is your motivation for such question? Do you want some deformation of sympletic structures using Poisson cohomology? If you want line bundles just compute the Picard group. If it satisfies such condition, there is just one cohomology class of line bundles, then it must be the trivial. If you exclude the trivial one, then the Picard group has order 2, I do not think it can happens, even if it happens probably the cohomology of the manifold will surject over the cyclic group of order 2, then if your manifold is compact, the sheaf cohomology will be equals to the Picard group.

Comment: Ok, after reading some stuff now I think that your question is when a manifold admits a prequantum line bundle. If so, the answer apparently is no, though I do not know differential cohomology properly to conclude this.

Comment: A line bundle and connection with curvature $\omega$ exist if and only if $[\omega/2\pi] \in H^2(M;\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @EricO.Korman is this because $[\omega / 2\pi]$ is integral ?

Comment: You might want to see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782507/chern-weil-why-do-we-divide-by-2-pi/798594#798594

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John is right, if you are not asking for any particular properties, there are no conditions: trivial bundles are always possible.

Now, if you are interested in Chern classes and symplectic manifolds, you probably want some explanation about prequantum line bundles.

Considering tensor products of vector bundles and bundle isomorphisms, the group of equivalence classes of complex line bundles over a manifold $M$ is isomorphic to $\check{H}^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ (nice exercise, you should try this).

A inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ induces a homomorphism $\check{H}^2(M;\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow \check{H}^2(M;\mathbb{R})$ and under a identification $\check{H}^2(M;\mathbb{R})\cong H_{dR}^2(M;\mathbb{R})$ one has a homomorphism $\check{H}^2(M;\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow H_{dR}^2(M;\mathbb{R})$.
Therefore, given a fixed closed form $\omega\in\Omega^2(M;\mathbb{R})$ whose de Rham class $[\omega]$ lies in the image of the homomorphism $\check{H}^2(M;\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow H_{dR}^2(M;\mathbb{R})$, there are equivalence classes of complex line bundles with hermitian connexions such that their curvature is $-i\omega$. Note that the map $\check{H}^2(M;\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow H_{dR}^2(M;\mathbb{R})$ has a kernel.

You should not write, though, that the class of your de Rham form belongs to $\check{H}^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$, that is not the case (and it does not make any sense): to be integral really means to lie in the image of the aforementioned homomorphism.

P.D.: $2\pi$'s, $i$'s, and signs conventions are all different in the literature, just pick one that you like.

Comment: This is for smooth Line bundles over smooth manifolds, if you ask for holomorphic stuff, then there are some extra things to care about.